# check for duplicate lists Java 8

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8, duplicates

Given n lists, I want to find out if any two lists have exactly same elements. Below is code in Java 7.

```
public static <T> boolean hasduplicateList(List<List<T>> lists) {
    for (List<T> outerList : lists) {
        int count = 0;
        Set<T> outerSet = new HashSet<>(outerList);
        for (List<T> innerList : lists) {
            Set<T> innerSet = new HashSet<>(innerList);
            if (outerSet.equals(innerSet)) {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve same specially using Java8?

Comment: Do they need to be in the same order to be considered duplicate?

Comment: @shmosel Based on the OPs code, they shouldn't (the OP converts the Lists to Sets before comparing them).

Comment: @Eran Right. I'll delete my answer if OP confirms.

Comment: @Eran u r right. Fixed it

Comment: @shmosel no, order doesn't matter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since in your Java 7 code you convert the `List`s to `Set`s before comparing them, it seems that you want to check whether at least 2 of the input `List`s have the same set of elements (ignoring duplicates or order).

You can achieve this in Java 8 by streaming the `List` and converting it to a `Stream` of `Set`s. Then all you have to do is find if the number of distinct `Set`s is smaller than the size of the input `List` :

```
public static <T> boolean hasduplicateList(List<List<T>> lists) {
  return 
    lists.stream()  // create a <Stream<List<T>>
         .map(HashSet::new) // transform Stream<List<T>> to Stream<HashSet<T>> 
         .distinct() // keep only distinct Sets
         .count() < lists.size();
}
```

Test :

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{ 
    List<String> alist = Arrays.asList ("a","b","c");
    List<String> blist = Arrays.asList ("b","c","c","a");
    List<String> clist = Arrays.asList ("e","d","c","a");
    List<List<String>> llist1 = Arrays.asList (alist,blist);
    List<List<String>> llist2 = Arrays.asList (alist,clist);
    System.out.println ("has dups? " + hasduplicateList (llist1));
    System.out.println ("has dups? " + hasduplicateList (llist2));
}
```

Output :

```
has dups? true
has dups? false
```

Comment: You can use `HashSet::new`.

Answer (score 0):

I inspired from @Eran 's answer for an integer array and It worked.
Code is :

```
int a = {1,2,3,4,5};
boolean isAnyDuplicate = Arrays.stream(a).distinct().count() < a.length;
System.out.println("First is" + isAnyDuplicate);
int b = {1,2,2,4,5};
isAnyDuplicate = Arrays.stream(b).distinct().count() < b.length;
System.out.println("Second is" + isAnyDuplicate);
```